# Escape -LiteralPath

Tags: powershell, escaping, registry

I've added PowerShell to my context menu by setting:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell\command]
@="powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V'"
```

This works quite well, except for a folder that I have brilliantly named `Ash's docs`. Which fails with:

```
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

From the [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-6#parameters) docs:

> Specifies a path of the location. The value of the **LiteralPath** parameter is used exactly as it is typed. No characters are interpreted as wildcard characters. If the path includes escape characters, enclose it in single quotation marks. Single quotation marks tell PowerShell not to interpret any characters as escape sequences.

Is my option here to use `-Path` and hope I don't have directories with possible wildcards in their names? Or can one escape the single quote in `%V`?

Comment: `'%V'` -> `\"%V\"`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - same error. Have also tried the `Here strings` `@"%V"@` with no luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the path in double quotes rather than single quotes. Double quotes can't appear in a path. The double quotes must be escaped twice, though: for the .reg file and for the PowerShell invocation.

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell\command]
@="powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath \\\"%V\\\""
```

Comment: @Ash I tested this before posting, so I seriously doubt that doesn't work unless you did something wrong.

Comment: Yep, user fault - I was testing the `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell\command]` instead of `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell\command]`
Thanks!